# How can I getValue() of specific number of characters in a cell/range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, google-sheets-api

I am trying to find a way to only getValue() of a specific number of characters in a cell/range. For example:

I'm looking at this data in a cell= 4/17/2019 10:15:48
I want to take that data and compare it to another data to determine if it is today or not. The issue is I don't care if it's 10:15:48. I just want to know if it was done on 4/17/2019.

Is it possible to getValue of the cell, but only take the first 9 characters instead of the entire cell data.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `var res = str.substring(0, 9);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, it supposes that the value of `4/17/2019 10:15:48` is put in a cell "A1" of the active sheet. In this case, how about the following sample script? I thought that when the value retrieved by `getValues()` is a date object, the result you want cannot be retrieved. So in this modification, I used `getDisplayValue()` for retrieving the value.

#### Sample script:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var value = sheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValue();
var res = value.substr(0, 9);
Logger.log(res)
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve values from several cells, you can also use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues).

#### References:

- [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue())
- [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I got it working in my code! I'm still new to this stuff and I don't know all the functions so it helps so much when I have a resource to get information from people like you! Thanks again!

Comment: Would you be able to explain the difference between getValue() and getDisplayValue()?

Comment: @Neros Thank you for replying. I apologize for my incomplete answer. About the different between ``getValue()`` and ``getDisplayValue()``, in the above situation, when the value is retrieved by ``getValue()``, the retrieved value is a date object. On the other hand, ``getDisplayValue()`` returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range. I think that testing this will help you understand.

Comment: @Neros The official documents of both methods are [``getValue()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) and [``getDisplayValue()``](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()).

Comment: Wonderful. That makes sense and I also learned that if you want something to equal a displayValue you have to make it a displayValue as well. Haha. Thank you again!